# Magento vs mass change attributes/inventory/etc

Tags: magento-1.9, massaction

Trying to update some things in products so what I've done is:

```
$attribute_code = use_config_manage_stock;
$attributeValue = 1;

$data = $attributeCode.' = '.$attributeValue;
Mage::log($data, NULL,'changes.log');
$attrData = array( $attributeCode => $attributeValue );
$storeId = 0;
//getting allIds from catalog/products
$allProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
//connection - just in case ...
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
//but next line is causing error 500.
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')-> updateAttributes($allPro‌ductIds, $attrData, $storeId)){
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($allPro‌ductIds, $attrData, $storeId);
```

What I've done wrong?
I can loop through and update all the products one by one but if I can do it using this "->updateAttributes" ... what is the problem?

Comment: What are the details of the `Error 500` you've mentioned? ;)

Comment: in console :) once I execute script in console I can see an error message 500 :) and that's it, nothing specific. Actually it says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Yes, yes, but your error log should always show you some further details on 500's - in most cases in there the answer is hidden already.

Comment: 500
Internal Server Error - that's it or I don't know where to look at.

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')-> updateAttributes($allPro‌ductIds, $attrData, $storeId)){` what's that supposed to do - doesn't seem like valid syntax at all to me?

Comment: Update all products using updateAttributes() method. I googled it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71824/discussion-between-christoph-farnleitner-and-robert-a).

Comment: Still can't make it work :(